# Minimum of two real measures

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\mu_1, \mu_2$ be real measures on $(X, \mathfrak{M})$

I want to show that $\mu(E) = min(\mu_1(E), \mu_2(E))$ is a real measure.

I proved that $\Sigma_{i=1}^\infty \mu(E_i) \le \mu(E)$ if $(E_i)_{i=1}^\infty$ are disjoint and $E = \cup_{i=1}^\infty E_i$.

I want to prove other direction($\ge$) of the inequality, but I was stuck on this.

Would you give me some hint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is  not true. Here is a counter-example: Let $m$ be Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$, $\mu_1(E)=m(E \cap [0,\frac 1 2 ])$ and $\mu_2(E)=m(E \cap [\frac 1 2, 1 ])$. If $A=[0,\frac 1 2 ]$ you can check that $0=\mu(A)+\mu(A^{c}) \neq 1=\mu ([0,1])$.